# Writing floating point numbers in single precision to file in R?

Tags: r, floating-point, compression, precision, single-precision

I understand that R doesn't have a floating point format in single precision. However, I'm writing a very large number of data points from R to file, and I'd like to store them as single precision floats, rather than double precision. I don't need good accuracy on these numbers.

Any way I can do that? I want to save as much space as possible, and even compression or dumping as binary isn't enough.

Edit: Is there a way to write .rds files as single precision floats?

Thanks!

Comment: does this help? http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/floating-point-in-single-precision-td2269833.html

Comment: I'd prefer if rds files could be stored in single precision format - possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `signif(data, X)` before `write.RDS` seems to work. Thanks all.